# Where do I connect the green wire from my dishwasher?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

I'm installing a new dishwasher and the dishwasher itself has the green wire, the cord (which is coming out of the floor of the house) doesn't have a green wire it has a black wire, a white wire, and  a copper wire hangin out of it. I know I should wrap the copper wire around the screw on the box, but what do I do with the green wire that is coming from the terminal on the dishwasher?

Answer (score 4):

The green wire is the dishwasher's ground wire. You hook it up to the circuit's ground wire, which is the bare copper one.

Comment: You also connect a grounding wire to the screw in the metal junction box.